# Pointer converter returning incorrect values

Tags: vb.net, pointers, hex, converters, z80

I'm trying to create a Z80 offset-pointer converter, but when I compile the program and test it, the output variables come out as zero.

The math behind it goes like this:

1. Take the offset that you wish to point to.
2. Take the last four digits of the offset, and cut off the rest.
3. If the offset is outside the range &H4000 - &H7FFF, it must be converted like this: (offset % &H4000) + &H4000. In other words:

   - If the offset is from &H0000 to &H3FFF, add &H4000 to the offset.
   - If the offset is from &H4000 to &H7FFF, do not do anything to the offset.
   - If the offset is from &H8000 to &HBFFF, subtract &H4000 from the offset.
   - If the offset is from &HC000 to &HFFFF, subtract &H8000 from the offset.

The code for the event that's called on click of the conversion button is like so:

```
Private Sub ConvertButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConvertButton.Click
    If GetOffsetRadioButton.Checked Then
        If OffsetTextBox.TextLength > 0 Then
            CoreActions.OffsetToPointer()
            PointerTextBox.Text = CoreActions.NewOffset
            PointerBankTextBox.Text = CoreActions.NewBank
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, here's the code behind the conversions, in the CoreActions module

```
Module CoreActions
    Friend HexOffset As String = CoreForm.OffsetTextBox.Text
    Friend PointerOffset As UInteger
    Friend PointerBank As UInteger
    Friend NewBank As String
    Friend NewOffset As String
    Friend Sub OffsetToPointer()
        Dim DecOffset As Integer = Val("&H" & HexOffset)
        PointerBank = DecOffset Mod 16384 ' 16384 = &H4000
        PointerOffset = DecOffset Mod 65536 ' 65536 = &H10000
        NewBank = Convert.ToString(PointerBank, 16)
        NewOffset = Convert.ToString(PointerOffset, 16)
    End Sub
End Module
```

What exactly is going wrong to where the outputs turn out as nothing? I don't get any exceptions or warning at runtime...

Comment: what you want to do is bitwise operation and bit shifting, right?

Comment: What's `PointerOffset` for? It looks to me like you just want to take `PointerBank` and add 4000h. If you really do want `PointerOffset` then you probably want to divide by 4000h as I don't think your modulo achieves anything. You also have the two things named the opposite way around to normal conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, this will give the result you want.

```
Dim FixedOffset As Integer = (DecOffset And &H3FFF) Or &H4000
```